# How to check what thread or object is still used or not?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

could anyone tell me how I can see which activities / threads remain active and are no longer called by my application?

For example, if I open an HTTP stream and then don't flush, but continue to open new ones, the memory used will continue to go up until the GC passes to clean up. is it possible to somehow see which threads or objects etc that have been generated and are not used for a given time x?

The reason for this request is due to the fact that having a server deployed with an application, this continues to increase the memory incrementally up to the limit whereby the GC is forced to intervene to re-establish a stable memory situation.

I don't know if it can be helpful in this analysis but the gcc parameters are set to:

-Xms8g -Xmx8g -XX: PermSize = 1024 XX: MaxPermSize = 1024

the machine's ram is 18g.

thanks to all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether an object is still used, perform a full GC. There isn't a short cut for this action.

You don't know if an object is needed until a garbage collection is performed.

> the memory used will continue to go up until the GC passes to clean up.

This is normal in a JVM. To improve performance, you want to reuse expensive objects, and not worry too much about cheap objects. You also need to tune the GC so that when it does run, it doesn't impact your application too much.

NOTE: Perm Gen was dropped in Java 8, and from March 2019, only Java 12 has free updates from Oracle, so will need to consider upgrading at some point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But since it is not possible to carry out these checks, is it possible instead to set a precise time in which to oblige the passage of the GC? Because I can't find this option, only options that suggest decreasing the heap size making it intervene automatically more frequently.

Comment: Unless you are using the concurrent collector (which you perhaps should consider) you are better off having the GC run when it needs to.

Comment: @kajim7 what do you hope to get from such a feature? The memory is there and it makes no difference to it whether it has been marked as “free” or “used”. The garbage collector will run when it needs the memory to be available to new allocations. Before that, “free” and “used” are only meaningless numbers.

Comment: @Holger The problem is related to the fact that the memory grows up to the limit and then a full gc goes into execution, this happens about once a week. The continuous increase in the use of memory leads to a deterioration of performance. I would therefore like to avoid the continuous increase of memory and to do so at the moment the only solution that I can implement is to carry out a GC operation more often (ideally at night when the system has fewer requests) since from what xxxx reported it is not possible to see threads, objects etc that are active but not used for a given time x.

Comment: @kajim7 You shouldn't be seeing a slow down as more of the memory is used. This could happen if your machine is over committed. i.e. the process is much bigger than the heap size or this isn't the only application running and part of the JVM is swapping. You should check how large the total process gets, much memory is actively swapping when it is slow and possibly reduce the heap/process size.

Comment: @kajim7 you get exactly what you asked for. You specified `-Xms8g`, i.e. an *initial heapsize* of 8g, matching the maximum heap size specified via `-Xmx8g`, hence, the JVM will utilize the specified amount of memory. But since you since you said your machine has 18g there should be no performance problem, unless your machine is over-committed, as Peter Lawrey said. That would imply that the total amount of memory used by all processes exceeds the 18g significantly.